# Woocommerce checkout form after filling gives error "Fill in the required fields"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have worked on a website that was built many years ago by a developer who is not updating it. recently I have added Woocommerce. but there is a problem. after filling the checkout form there is an error msg appears saying please fill in all the required fields although filling them all. it happens for all payment gateways. but if the user logged in it works and proceed to Paypal or whatever payment gateway. so this problem happens only if the user is not logged in.
I have dequeued the javascript files and deactivated the plugins and there is no way. is there any idea?

Comment: Are all the fields the  same for a logged in user and  a non logged in user?

Comment: yes. noticing that I'm hiding two fields with CSS display none.

Comment: it works when I'm logged in. but if it is a visitor it gives him woocommerce error msg fill in the required fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is most likely a primary key for the table. When a user signs up they enter the data into the SQL DB so it will not render an error for a signed up user to make a purchase. If a user is not signed up the information will need to be entered for your database to be relational(SQL will have a requirement for this data). This is the  reason you are rendering the error. Your fix is one of the following:
1)Display the required entry field by commenting out the css.
2)Depending on the size of the shop and how much work you need to do it might be faster and easier to rebuild it.
3)Rewrite the  Database from normal  form.

Comment: cancelled display:none and it worked. Thanks so much for help